# A phototransistor with LED and resistance in emitter

Tags: feedback, phototransistor, emitter-follower

Earlier I used a simple phototransistor arrangement to detect an on/off signal via a laser pulse.

I connected the collector to Vcc(5V), and emitter was grounded through a resistance. The base was unconnected.

As soon as the laser would bias the transistor, I would be able to observe about 4V at the emitter. Without the laser biasing (and in the normal room lightening condition) the transistor would not bias and I will get 0 reading at emitter.

However for debugging purposes I connected a LED in the emitter circuit as well. But got very strange results. Now the transistor was being biased in the normal light conditions. I am getting about 1-2V at emitter without laser biasing.

I understand that a resistance in emitter causes feedback, and think that LED might be giving a non-linear feedback or something. Is this the reason or am I missing something completely?

Also the transistor starts to work normally as soon as the LED is removed.
Once the transistor is biased with laser the LED glows normally, but even without the laser biasing, the LED does glow although very dimly.

Comment: Dhruv, you need to put a link to the specifications of your phototransistor.

Comment: I don't have any specifications sheet... At our place we don't get to know the model number or the specs.. Sad story.

Comment: Is it possibly from essentialscrap.com/toycar ?? That is where the picture of a phototransistor that you posted was located. I found they had specifications for that phototransistor on that site. At least a part number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transistor's collector emitter leakage current is enough to build up a voltage across the LED. You can solve the situation by connecting a large'ish resistor in parallel to the LED. That way the leakage current has a path to ground again. When the photo transistor gets biased by the laser, the current should be large enough for a voltage build up across the resistor to light the LED.

You probably need a series resistor for the LED too, you didn't mention that in your question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL0uMj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The mentioned 2k is just an guesstimate (\$2\text{k}\Omega × 100\mu\text{A} = 200\text{mV}\$) which sounds acceptable and in practice may be better than that). Best is to measure the current through the transistor when not being lit and calculate an acceptable resistor value for that current.

The series resistor should limit the current through the LED to maybe 10 or 20mA (\$\dfrac{V^+-V_{LED}}{10\text{mA}} = \dfrac{V^+-2\text{V}}{10\text{mA}}\$). Also check the optocoupler's maximum current to be sure it can handle 10mA.

Comment: Well in my circuit I connect LED in series with a resistance without the parallel one. Maybe the leakage current in the collector-emitter junction is causing the LED to dimly light up in absence of biasing.

But what I still don't understand that in absence of laser, why do I still get the voltage at the emitter end. Since the transistor is unbiased, shouldn't all the voltage drop from collector to emitter leaving 0 volts at emitter?

Why does a LED change the situation?

And although I get your calculations but I dont get how connecting a resistance with LED solves the problem...

Comment: in absence of ... ?

Comment: haha sorry... it adds the comment as soon as i press enter and i always forget that... newbie here :P

Comment: An LED has a very high resistance for low currents. So it needs only a tiny current to lift the emitter voltage (to the level where the LED starts to conduct). By using a resistor in parallel to the LED, you effectively lower the resistance to a level where the voltage build-up is much lower.

Comment: ohh... now I get it... The minority current from collector to emitter is independent of the resistance in emitter and adding LED adds a very large resistance to emitter circuit. This in in turn adds increases the voltage level. Did I get it correctly? Thanks :D

Comment: That is my theory, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The Led glows a bit because the photo transistor is not in the dark. 
In the dark, the [photo-transistor](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/stuff/other/bpw14n.pdf) only lets about 1nA of current flow. That is not enough to light up the LED.

Other than that, prior answers are spot on, for getting the response you want.